# null pointer exception during a function call

Tags: java, android, string, nullpointerexception, function-call

I am getting a null pointer exception when I am calling a function.

 Here is my code:

```
    try{
            .....
            String [] forForm = new String[5];
            forForm[0] = new String(parentElement.getNodeName());
            forForm[1] = new String(childElement1.getNodeName());
            forForm[2] = new String(ce1);
            forForm[3] = new String(childElement2.getNodeName());
            forForm[4] = new String(ce2);
            Log.e(tag,forForm.toString());
            showForm(forForm);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(tag, "error in try: "+e.toString());
    }
```

Here is my output :

```
09-10 21:58:47.919: ERROR/ca(867): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?><LoginInfo><Username>un</Username><Password>pw</Password></LoginInfo>
09-10 21:58:47.999: ERROR/ca(867): Username: un
09-10 21:58:47.999: ERROR/ca(867): Password: pw
09-10 21:58:48.019: ERROR/ca(867): [Ljava.lang.String;@44ed5570
09-10 21:58:48.019: ERROR/ca(867): in show form1
09-10 21:58:48.040: ERROR/ca(867): error in try: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Why am I getting a null pointer exception even though there is a memory location for forForm?

**EDIT:**

```
private void showForm(String[] forForm) {
        Log.e(tag, "in show form1");
        LinearLayout ol = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.OuterLayout);
        LinearLayout [] il = new LinearLayout [2];
        EditText [] et = new EditText[2];
        TextView [] tv = new TextView[3];

        tv[0].setText(forForm[0]);
        tv[0].setTextSize(30);
        tv[0].setLayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Log.e(tag, "in show form2");
        il[0].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            tv[1].setText(forForm[1]);
            tv[1].setTextSize(20);
            tv[1].setLayoutParams(
                    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
            il[0].addView(tv[1]);

            et[0].setText(forForm[2]);
            et[0].setId(1111);
            et[0].setTextSize(20);
            et[0].setLayoutParams(
                    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
            il[0].addView(et[0]);
            Log.e(tag, "in show form3");
        il[1].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            tv[2].setText(forForm[3]);
            tv[2].setTextSize(20);
            tv[2].setLayoutParams(
                    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
            il[1].addView(tv[1]);

            et[1].setText(forForm[2]);
            et[1].setId(2222);
            et[1].setTextSize(20);
            et[1].setLayoutParams(
                    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
            il[1].addView(et[1]);
            Log.e(tag, "in show form4");    
        ol.addView(tv[0]);
        ol.addView(il[0]);
        ol.addView(il[1]);

        Log.e(tag, "Set Content View.");
        this.setContentView(ol);
    }
```

In the output, I am getting till "in showform 1"

Comment: try stepping through your debugger.

Comment: ok. will do and let you know.

Comment: add the full stack trace of your exception please, may be the array forForm or the other variables parentElement ...etc are the source of the exception. to make sure about that, replace your string by simple string like ( " forForm1 ,forForm2 ..etc ) and see if the problem come from the forForm array or the other vars : parentElement ...etc

Comment: Log the entire stack trace rather than just `e.toString()`. Remember: [Stacktrace or GTFO](http://i.imgur.com/jacoj.jpg)

Comment: How to do stacktrace. I am sorry I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be happening with .getnodename(), if the node is not present, you are working on a null node, check for sure that the node is present before working on that node with .getnodename().

Comment: I am getting a value for all indices of forForm. I'll edit the qn to show them

Answer (score 1):

Assuming forForm is not null, as showed in the initial post, then the only explanation I can think of is that showForm is the one throwing the exception.

You have initializated a TextView array with 3 null TextView, you never construct those TextViews.

Comment: Also 2 `null` `LinearLayout`s and 2 `EditText`s.